# Page import in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

The charset and page Encoding will depend on the variable. I was wondering what wrong with my code in regards to concatenating the page import.

```
<% String charSet = RM.getCharSet(); %>
<% page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset="%><%=charSet%> <%pageEncoding="%><%=charSet%>
```

using my phone so it's kinda difficult to indent the codes. Thank you'

Comment: You forgot to paste the code alltogether.

Comment: Wasn't able to indent it. Glad someone edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I think that attribute cannot be set dynamically. Instead, I would set it directly from the controller when writing the response. If your response is already written, you could create a filter that will create a new response as wrapper and will use the data in the response written by the controller (servlet or whatever you're using) and also set the charset from a request attribute (or however you want/need it).